# Extend a function that accepts List<Contact> as Input parameter to accept List<Account> also

Tags: apex

When Contact record is deleted then I am adding a reference in custom obj (Record_Delete_History__c). Currently for the same there is an helper class "contactDelRecords" that accepts List Contact>. I like to use the same helper class for Account deletion as well, i.e. I would pass Account object from Account Trigger to same contactDelRecords method and use para List SObject> instead of List Contact>. How can I achieve using sObject and typecasting to Account/Contact? Thanks for your help.

```
static List<Record_Delete_History__c> listRecBackup = new List<Record_Delete_History__c>();

public static void contactDelRecords(List<Contact> deletedCons){
    for(Contact cont : deletedCons) {
        if(String.isNotBlank(cont.MasterRecordId)) {
            //Operation is Merge Contact
            listRecBackup.add(new Record_Delete_History__c(
                    Action__c = 'Merge',
                    Impacted_ID__c = cont.Id,                       
                    MDM_Record_Id__c = cont.MDM_Contact_ID__c,
                    Object_type__c = 'Contact',
                    Reference_Id__c = cont.MasterRecordId 
            ));  
        }
        else {//Operation is Delete Contact
            listRecBackup.add(new Record_Delete_History__c(
                    Action__c = 'Delete',
                    Impacted_ID__c = cont.Id,
                    MDM_Record_Id__c = cont.MDM_Contact_ID__c,
                    Object_type__c = 'Contact'                       
            ));
        }         
    }
    if (listRecBackup.size() > 0)
        insert listRecBackup;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use polymorphism like this:

```
public static void myMethod(List<SObject> myRecords){
  for(SObject record : myRecords){
    String name = record.get('Name');
  }
}
```

Basically treat every object as an SObject and then access the properties through the `.get('propertyName')` and `.set('propertyName', 'propertyValue')` methods.